# Переклад "в данном случае" українською мовою

Tags: переклад, from-russian

Цікавить правильний переклад російського словосполучення "в данном случае" українською мовою.

У СУМ знайшла вживання "[у даному разі](http://sum.in.ua/s/danyj)"

Чи можна вважати такий переклад адекватним згідно з правил української мови?

Comment: пропоную вам додати посилання сюди: http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=20865&page=707 і сказати, що тут цей вираз вже прибрали, а тому виникають сумніви, чи це сталий вираз, а чи необґрунтована калька, наприклад, бо поки що не надто зрозуміло, чому саме ви не довіряєте першому джерелу (хоч ми йому тут і всі не надто довіряємо).

Comment: Див. також: [«Чи варто в українській мові вживати слово „даний“?»](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/2992). Коротко кажучи, «даний» у цьому значенні (тобто не у випадку, коли хтось щось комусь дає — адже «раз»/«випадок» не можна комусь дати) — канцеляризм. Варто у більшості випадків уживати «у цьому разі», «в такому разі», «у цьому випадку», «в такому випадку» і т.ін., а не «у даному разі» чи «у даному випадку» (хоча останні теж, мабуть, доречні в деяких сферах мовлення).

Comment: «Наразі», «в цьому випадку»

Answer (score 5):

[Уроки державної мови (з газети «Хрещатик»)](http://slovopedia.org.ua/30/53396/26320.html)

> ***Даний*** – це дієприкметник, утворений від дієслова дати. Виникає
>   запитання: хто той час дав? Хто дав ту роботу (доручення, завдання)? У
>   названих зворотах, якщо хоч трохи подумати, лексема даний не має
>   сенсу. Чому не сказати без бюрократичних викрутасів нині, тепер
>   (замість у даний час), у цій справі, у цьому творі? Замість “на даному
>   підприємстві” – “на цьому підприємстві”, замість ***“у даному разі” – “в
>   цьому разі”.*** Можна дібрати й інші повноцінні вислови, радить відомий
>   лінгвіст Олександра Сербенська.

[Не офіційне джерело](http://www.armyfm.com.ua/slovo-danij-ce-kalka-z-ros%D1%96jsko%D1%97-movi-/)

> ...слово «даний» здебільшого є канцеляризмом і у наведених прикладах
>   ще й калькою з російської мови. Тому його варто уникати. Отже, замість
>   “у даному батальйоні” говоримо “у цьому батальйоні”, замість “у даному
>   разі” – “у цьому разі”, «у цьому випадку», «за цих умов (обставин)». А
>   ще для перекладу слова ***«данный»*** можна вживати такі слова, як
>   ***«зазначений», «наведений», «згаданий»*** та ін.

В СУМ-20 в визначені **[ДАНИЙ](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=20865&page=707)** вираз *"у даному разі"* відсутній.

На мою думку, краще зробити переклад ***"у цьому разі"***.

Answer (score 1):

[Російсько-український словник](https://r2u.org.ua/data/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%96%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%85%20%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%96%D0%B2%20%281959%29.pdf) пропонує варіанти:

**У даному разі**

**У цьому випадку**

А от сайт [WikiDot](http://ros-ukr-idioms.wikidot.com/v) пропонує лише один варіант перекладу - "у цьому випадку".

Але якщо перевірити подані приклади на сайті [Онлайн Корректор](http://onlinecorrector.com.ua/%D1%83-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%86%D1%8C%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%96/), то бачимо:

Замініть нехарактерний для української мови **канцеляризм** у такому (цьому, тому, кращому) випадку на стилістично кращий варіант: у такому (цьому, тому, кращому) разі.

Отже варіанти перекладу:

**У такому разі**

**У цьому разі**

**У тому разі**

**У кращому разі**

Answer (score 1):

Білоус, Сербенська. Екологія українського слова (2003):

> Уживають: в даному випадку.
>
> Радимо: **в цьому разі, в цьому випадку.**

Головащук С. І. Російсько-український словник сталих словосполучень (2001):

> в данном случае — **в цьому випадку**

Олійник І. С., Сидоренко М. М. Українсько-російський фразеологічний словник (1978):

> **у цьому випадку (разі)** — в этом случае

Олейник И. С., Сидоренко М. М. Русско-украинский фразеологический словарь (1978):

> в данном случае — **в цьому випадку**

Окремі гардкорні лінґвісти на кшталт Іллі Данилюка і його онлайн-коректора [радять](http://onlinecorrector.com.ua/%D1%83-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%86%D1%8C%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%96/) заміняти "випадку" на "разі":

> Замініть нехарактерний для української мови канцеляризм *у такому (цьому, тому, кращому) **випадку*** на стилістично *кращий варіант*: *у такому (цьому, тому, кращому)* **разі.**

Отже погоджене поміж дослідниками правило - **перекладати "данный" як "цей"**, а деякі ще й радять вживати **не "випадку", а "разі".**

Answer (score -1):

А чому “у цьому випадку» чи «у цьому разі», а не «зараз» чи «поки»? Адже ми думає трохи інакше, ніж росіяни, тож росіянізми це не лише слова, а і певні сталі форми, які не властиві нам, зараз це канцеляризм «в данному случае».

> ```
> ЗА́РАЗ, присл.
>
> 2. У даний час, тепер.
> ```

> Ми в човні з тобою знову на
> Дніпрі. І тече ласкава мрійна хвиль габа, ой, колись кривава, зараз —
> голуба (Володимир Сосюра, II, 1958, 318).

[Поки](https://slovnyk.ua/index.php?swrd=%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8)

> ПОКИ. 1. присл. У даний момент, зараз

> - Як хоч, мамо, а поки така думка є в мене (Кв.-Осн., II, 1958, 103);

Comment: *А чому “у цьому випадку» чи «у цьому разі», а не «зараз» чи «поки»? Адже ми думає трохи інакше, ніж росіяни, тож росіянізми це не лише слова, а і певні сталі форми, які не властиві нам, зараз це канцеляризм «в данному случае».*

Ви відповідаєте питанням на питання. Така відповідь має місце у коментарях. У відповіді має бути відповідь, обгрунтована джерелами, без жодного суб'єктивізму, інакше це порушує правила. Читайте, перш ніж відповідати.
https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer
https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers